# Create a generalize method without losing types

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless

we have

```
private def insertUpdateDeleteFormDsList(dsList : List[FormDefinitionDataSourceRequestModel])(implicit formDefId:Int,subject:Subject,session: Session) : (List[(Int,Int)],Seq[FormDefinitionDataSourceRequestModel],Seq[FormDefinitionDataSourceRequestModel]) = {
val incomingIds = dsList.map( ds => (ds.dataSourceId,ds.dsTypeId) )

val existingIds = formDefinitionDatasources.filter(_.tenantId === subject.tenantId).filter(_.formDefId === formDefId).map( ds => (ds.dataSourceId,ds.dataSourceTypeId) ).list

val idsForDeletion = existingIds diff incomingIds
val idsForInsertion = incomingIds diff existingIds
val idsForUpdate = existingIds diff idsForDeletion


val insertList = dsList.flatMap{ t => idsForInsertion collectFirst{ case (dsId,dsType) if(dsId == t.dataSourceId && dsType == t.dsTypeId)=> t} }
val updateList = dsList.flatMap{t=>idsForUpdate collectFirst {case (dsId,dsType) if(dsId == t.dataSourceId && dsType == t.dsTypeId)=> t}}

(idsForDeletion,updateList,insertList)

}
```

And other similar methods as

```
private def insertUpdateDelDataInstances(instances: List[Instance])(implicit subject: Subject, session: Session): (Seq[Instance], Seq[Instance], Seq[Instance]) = {
val incomingIds = instances.map(_.id)
val existingIds = dataSourceInstanceNew.filter(_.tenantId === subject.tenantId).map(_.id).list
val idsForDeletion = existingIds diff incomingIds
val idsForInsertion = incomingIds diff existingIds
val idsForUpdate = existingIds diff idsForDeletion

val deleteList = instances.flatMap{ t => idsForDeletion collectFirst{ case id if(id == t.id)=> t} }
val insertList = instances.flatMap{ t => idsForInsertion collectFirst{ case id if(id == t.id)=> t} }
val updateList = instances.flatMap{t=>idsForUpdate collectFirst {case id if(id === t.id)=> t}}
(deleteList,updateList,insertList)
}
```

There are similar method occurrences elsewhere. Every time `List[T]` will be passed as a method argument where `T` is always a `case class`. now how `val incomingIds` gets constructed is dependent on specific `case class` attributes.

We want to create a generalized function which can accept a `List[T]` and possibly `incomingIds` and return a desired tuple to avoid writing similar looking boilerplate every time.

If say logic was to "always" use `T` `case class` 's `id` attribute then I can easily create a parent `trait` with `id` and have all `case class`es mixin the trait - but that's not the case here. preparing `val incomingIds` depend on different `case class` attributes depending on where in the code they are called from.

Illustrating below

```
def generalizedInsertUpdateDeleteList[T](data:List[T],incomingIds:List[Int], existingIds:List[Int] )(implicit subject: Subject, session:Session) = {
val idsForDeletion = existingIds diff incomingIds
val idsForInsertion = incomingIds diff existingIds
val idsForUpdate = existingIds diff idsForDeletion

/*
//what's the best way to generalize comparison inside  collectFirst?
//to use case class attribute names from `T`. Was thinking if Structural type can help but not sure if that
//can quite work unless there is a way to pass in arguments in a structural type? 


val deleteList = data.flatMap{ t => idsForDeletion collectFirst{ case id if(id == t.id)=> t} }
val insertList = data.flatMap{ t => idsForInsertion collectFirst{ case id if(id == t.id)=> t} }
val updateList = data.flatMap{ t => idsForUpdate collectFirst {case id if(id === t.id)=> t}}
*/
```

Can shapeless help here if no other cleaner way to achieve this using standard scala/scalaz APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a type class with a `PartialFunction` which can be used inside `collectFirst`.

```
trait IUD[T, IdType] {
  // returns a partial function which will be used in collectFirst
  def collectId(t: T): PartialFunction[IdType, T]
}
```

We can create `IUD` instances for your two methods :

```
// I chose (Long, Long) as type of (ds.dataSourceId,ds.dsTypeId) 
type FormModel = FormDefinitionDataSourceRequestModel
implicit object FormModelIUD extends IUD[FormModel, (Long, Long)] {
  def collectId(t: FormModel): PartialFunction[(Long, Long), FormModel] = {
    case (dsId,dsType) if(dsId == t.dataSourceId && dsType == t.dsTypeId) => t
  }
}

implicit object InstanceIUD extends IUD[Instance, Int] {
  def collectId(t: Instance): PartialFunction[Int, Instance] = {
    case id if id == t.id => t
  }
}
```

We can use the `IUD` type class in your `generalizedInsertUpdateDeleteList` method :

```
def generalizedIUDList[T, IdType](
  data: List[T], incomingIds: List[IdType], existingIds: List[IdType]
)(implicit 
  subject: Subject, session: Session, iud: IUD[T, IdType]
) = {
  val idsForDeletion = existingIds diff incomingIds
  val idsForInsertion = incomingIds diff existingIds
  val idsForUpdate = existingIds diff idsForDeletion

  def filterIds(ids: List[IdType]) = 
    data.flatMap(instance => ids collectFirst(iud.collectId(instance)) )

  val deleteList = filterIds(idsForDeletion)
  val insertList = filterIds(idsForInsertion)
  val updateList = filterIds(idsForUpdate)

  (deleteList,updateList,insertList)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Shapeless's records provide a type-safe way to abstract over case classes with a particular member name. For example:

```
import shapeless._, ops.record.Selector

def getId[A, R <: HList](a: A)(implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
  sel: Selector[R, Witness.`'id`.T]
): sel.Out = sel(gen.to(a))
```

And then:

```
scala> case class Foo(id: String)
defined class Foo

scala> case class Bar(id: Int, name: String)
defined class Bar

scala> getId(Foo("12345"))
res0: String = 12345

scala> getId(Bar(123, "bar"))
res1: Int = 123
```

If you need to constrain the type of the `id` member, you can use `Selector.Aux`:

```
def getIntId[A, R <: HList](a: A)(implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
  sel: Selector.Aux[R, Witness.`'id`.T, Int]
): Int = sel(gen.to(a))
```

Now `getIntId(Bar(123, "bar"))` will compile, but `getIntId(Foo("12345"))` won't.

Answer (score 0):

`collectFirst` accepts a `PartialFunction`, in your case `PartialFunction[Int, T]` I think?

You could pass the partial functions in as parameters to your `generalizedInsertUpdateDeleteList` method, then only these would need to be defined each time.